# What were the origins of the Bulgarian people?

Tags: demography, hungary, bulgaria

In my home history lessons and books it is stated that Bulgarians and Hungarians were, in earlier times, pure Turks but they lost their Turkish features over time when they met Christendom.

Really, once upon a time the Bulgarians and Hungarians were Turks?